# Destructuring assignment not working in node_modules meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a meteor 1.4.1.1 app with *ecmascript@0.5.8*. When I write the following expression in any file in the main meteor app, everything works.

`const {a, b} = {a:1, b:2};`

But when the same expression is in a JS file in *node_modules/some-module*,the meteor app fails with the following error:

```
W20160910-00:34:14.284(5.5)? (STDERR) const {a,b} = {a: 1, b: 2};
W20160910-00:34:14.284(5.5)? (STDERR)       ^ 
W20160910-00:34:14.285(5.5)? (STDERR) 
W20160910-00:34:14.285(5.5)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
W20160910-00:34:14.285(5.5)? (STDERR)     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
W20160910-00:34:14.285(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
W20160910-00:34:14.285(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
W20160910-00:34:14.286(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
W20160910-00:34:14.286(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Module.Mp.load (/home/chaudharyp/.meteor/packages/babel-compiler/.6.9.1.s4764v++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/node/runtime.js:16:23)
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the module is not getting transpiled.

Comment: yes. that is because babel is unable to understand the destructuring assignment syntax. right? But what I don't understand is why this is happening only in *node_modules* folder's modules and not in the main meteor app files.

Comment: Chances are Babel is not configured to run on dependency modules at all, usually dependencies would be compiled separately before it has been published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically npm packages are distributed in es5, so es6 packages get transpiled before being published.  Thus most build setups tell babel to ignore the node_modules folder.  This is important because it would seriously slow the build down if it tried to transpile all of your npm packages.  I'm not familiar with this meteor setup, but I'm sure it's following this common practice.

Typically you wouldn't mess around in your node_modules folder directly anyway.  If you're developing your own package and don't want to have to publish and update every time you make a change, you should try [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).  Then you can point your package's "main" to a folder like /dist where you transpile code to.  When you transpile over in your package project, your meteor project will pick up the updates.